# Configure HTML Tidy to ignore PHP short start and end tags when inside html attributes

Tags: php, htmltidy

How can I keep HTML Tidy from converting PHP short tags when used as values in html attributes?

Here's an example of what it currently does. It converts this:

```
<input value='<?=$variable?>'>
```

to this:

```
<input value='&lt;?=$variable?&gt;'>
```

I want HTML Tidy to ignore PHP short tags. Any config options that change this?

==

To simplify, is there a way to have HTML Tidy just avoid doing HTML entity conversion? If it would just not convert < and >, that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it could be done `Tidy` doesn't work too well with `php` - it might choke if your `php` code contains quote marks etc. Also `Tidy` might throw warnings about missing attributes if they're output by `php`.

You could replace all `<?$variable?>` to `<#$variable#>` before running `Tidy` and then replace them back.
In the console, for example like this:

```
sed -i 's/<?=\(.*\)?>/<#\1#>/g' yourfile.php
tidy -m yourfile.php
sed -i 's/<#\(.*\)#>/<?=\1?>/g' yourfile.php
```

The first line converts `<?=$variable?>` to `<#$variable#>` inside file,
the second runs tidy in place and updates the file,
The third line converts <#$variable#> back to `<?=$variable>`.

Answer (score 1):

Unprocessed PHP is not compatible with HTML (except few most trivial cases), and Tidy has only superficial support for it.

There are countless ways in which Tidy can actually *cause* errors in the document, because it won't understand what PHP generates and how it interacts with other markup.

To get correct and reliable results you should postprocess HTML-only output. You can do that by adding Tidy filter in PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start('ob_tidyhandler');
?>
```

This will impact runtime performance, but it's not a problem for most sites as Tidy is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-process your php:

by adding comments by converting `<?` to `<!--<?`,  and `?>` to `?>-->`

`<input value='<?=$variable?>'>`

would become

`<input value='<!--<?=$variable?>-->'>`

after running HTMLtidy, you would do the opposite.

1. pre-process by adding comment tags
2. run HTMLtidy
3. un-pre-process...

Answer (score -1):

A quick way is to just replace all `<?=` with `<?php echo`

Comment: doing what I said will keep html tidy away